# Repeating elements inside my recycler view problem

Tags: java, android

Inside my recycler view im getting repeat elements (textview, floating action button, etc) for every entry in my database. It makes no sense at all. Also, when you click my actual FAB it works and takes you to its intent. However the other copies inside of the recycler view don't. I don't want them to work nor do I want them there. Please help!

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/termListRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TermIdView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/termListActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/termListRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TermIdView"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Term Info Here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TermIdView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```


I've tried everything. Even ChatGPT. been at it for 12 hours..im a beginner so please help
````